# "*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: realloc(): invalid next size:" when reading multiple files in C

Tags: c, linux, file

I am developing an application that reads the files of a directory, opens them and copies the content of them into a buffer. The opening of a single file is conducted by a single function, and returns a pointer to the read input. However, when I run the function more than once, that is I open more than one file and read the contents of it, I get the following error:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x096a9008 ***
```

This is my source code:

```
char *
readFile(char *filename)
{
    int fp, numread, i;
    char buffer[READ_SIZE], *content;

    content = malloc(READ_SIZE);
    fp = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    i=1;
    for(;;){
            printf("%d\n", i);
            numread = read(fp,buffer,READ_SIZE);
            if(numread == -1){
                    printf("error opening file\n");
                    exit(0);
            }
            if(numread < READ_SIZE){
                    buffer[numread] = '\0';
                    content = realloc(content, READ_SIZE*i+numread);
                    strcat(content, buffer);
                    break;
            }
            content = realloc(content, READ_SIZE*i);
            if(content == NULL)
                    exit(0);
            strcat(content, buffer);
            i++;
    }

    close(fp);
    return content;
}
```

The output after reading two files looks like this:

```
1071
1072
1
2
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x096a9008 ***
```

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: As the answers below point out, you have issues.  You're mixing a binary `read` with a string/character based `strcat`.  Should be using `memcpy` for binary data returned from `read`.  Since `strcat` is looking for zero-byte terminators on the chunks of data, it's overrunning the bounds of buffer[], overwriting the value of *content, causing `realloc` to refuse to resize a non-valid memory pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `malloc` does not initialize the memory it allocates. The contents of that memory is indeterminate, so using it in any way leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). And you do use it uninitialized, when you call `strcat`.

To know where to add the second string to the first, the `strcat` must find the string terminator. But by doing so it has to read the (uninitialized) memory you pass as the first argument, and if it doesn't find the terminator it will continue reading beyond the limits of your allocated memory until it finds the terminator. And if it finds the terminator beyond what you have allocated it will write the second string to that places, writing in unallocated memory.

There are two obvious solutions: Either use `calloc` instead, or set the first byte of the allocated memory to the string terminator.

---

As noted by simonc the buffer you read into is not terminated in all cases as well. Here you have two problems: The first that you don't terminate the string, the second that you haven't allocated enough memory to add the terminator.

Comment: Wonderful answer, totally correct about strcat, but what does the contents of memory have to do with the error indicated?  realloc doesn't care what's __in__ memory.  As @simonc states, OP should be using memcpy to copy the contents of buffer[], not strcat (or strncat!).  It's very likely that due to strcat's UB, it's overwriting the value of *content (which follows buffer[] on the stack allocated heap), causing realloc to complain since the memory block thus indicated by *content is invalid.  Basically, OP's issue is a UB generated buffer (buffer[]!) overrun, overwriting *content.

Comment: @lornix The allocation problem is not with the `realloc` call, but the initial `malloc` call.

Answer (score 2):

`strcat` operates on two nul-terminated buffers.  `content` points to uninitialised memory and `buffer` is only terminated if you read less data than expected.

You either need to terminate both `content` and `buffer` or copy memory using `memcpy` instead.

```
memcpy(content + ((i-1)*READ_SIZE), buffer, numread)
```

If you do this, be sure to increment `numread` on the final iteration when you add a terminator.